# WPF смена кнопок

Tags: c#, wpf

Задача:

Требуется по нажатию одной кнопки заменить её на другую и наоборот.

Написал такие стили для двух кнопок:

```
<Style x:Key="FindAppButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=StopSearch, Path=Visibility}" Value="Hidden">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


 <Style x:Key="StopSearchButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=FindApp, Path=Visibility}" Value="Hidden">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

По нажатию кнопки поиска, мельком видно, как она скрывается и появляется кнопка остановки, а потом обратно становится видимой. А события нажатия для этих кнопок вообще не срабатывают.

В чём дело?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша ошибка в том, вы в разметке пытаетесь решить вопрос, который, по хорошему, надо решать в `ViewModel`. Сделайте в вашей `VM` два свойства `StopSearchVisibility` и `FindAppVisibility` типа `bool` и к ним уже привяжите ваши кнопки.

Comment: Ну у меня сейчас по сути так и есть, только не через свойства, а через Tag кнопки(Тогда хватает одной кнопки). Я думал будет правильнее вынести эту логику имено в разметку.

Comment: @Сергей, разметка это то что видит пользователь, их может быть много разных для одного окна, поэтому никакую логику туда вносить не стоит, для этого и есть `VM`. Свойства `Tag` кнопок это тоже не правильно, судя по этому, можно сделать вывод что у вас вообще нет `VM` (то есть вы себе изобретаете бесплатный геморрой). Признавайтесь, вы раньше писали на `WinForm` :).

Comment: Я вообще с WPF работаю 1 неделю. На WinForm писал, но тоже не много.

Comment: Опишите поподробнее, как вы предлагаете пользоваться этими свойствами?

Comment: @Сергей, тогда вам надо почитать об архитектуре WPF, плохие привычки принесенные с других платформ могут очень простую задачу (как ваша) превратить в головоломку.

Comment: @Сергей, опишите публичный класс, как минимум, наследующий `INotifyPropertyChanged` (что бы свойства могли сообщать о своих изменениях), в нем сделайте, как минимум,  два вышеуказаных свойства. Объект класса должен создаваться или передаваться в класс окна(старницы), например в конструкторе. Этот класс в разметке укажите как `DataContext`. Свойства `Visibility` кнопок привяжите к свойствам этого объекта. Профит... Звучит долго и сложно, однако делается довольно быстро, и значительно облегчит вам работу

Comment: У меня есть такой класс, только назван он просто Model и хранит данные для представления.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45314/discussion-between-mirdin-and-).

Comment: Я не могу писать, похоже он просит залогиниться, хотя я уже это сделал. Раньше мог в чате общаться.

Comment: @Сергей (текст из чата) Тогда зачем вам использовать Tag добавьте поля в этот класс. Название правда не очень, если он хранит данные для представления, это уже не Model. Зачем все это надо, WPF разделяет работу дизайнера и программиста, в отличие от WinForm, позволяя им работать отдельно. Дизайнер может нарисовать много окон, с множеством разметок для каждого. Программист напишет одну VM

Comment: Хорошо, попробую сделать, как Вы советуете

Comment: Большое спасибо, всё получилось, только тип свойств не Boolean, а System.Windows.Visibility или просто Visibility.